# Where did Falcon go during the fight between Avengers and Ultron?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In [*Avengers: Age of Ultron* (2015)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2395427/), Falcon is only seen at the beginning and by the end of the movie when Captain America says: "Avengers, assemble".

- Falcon has been recruited into Avengers before the events of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.
- Where did he go when Avengers were fighting Ultron?

Comment: I think your answer is in Ant-Man

Comment: "Falcon has been recruited into Avengers before the events of Avengers: Age of Ultron." Are you sure about this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_(comics)#Film says otherwise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

During the party scene, Steve said he would have called up Sam, and Sam said he’s more than happy chasing down cold leads on their missing persons case (i.e. looking for Bucky). It’s very likely that Sam went right back to looking for Bucky after he left the party that night.

In the "real world", Anthony Mackie was in 5 movies the year Age Of Ultron was released, so it's likely he was too busy to commit to the project on a larger scale.

Comment: You forgot *Ant-Man* in your answer.